# Nested initializer lists don't construct the nested arrays as I would expect

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::array<std::array<double, 3>, 2>> arr =
    {
      {
        {2, 1, 0},
        {1, 1, 0}
      }
    };

    cout << "Array size " << arr.size() << endl;
}
```

I would expect this to return a vector of size 1, containing the 2d array that looks like this:

```
[
  [[2, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
]
```

However it returns a vector of size two, where the two arrays look like this:

```
[
  [[2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
]
```

It seems to me like it should be able to construct the two inner size 3 arrays and then use that to construct the single size 2 array to put that into the vector.

I am very confused. Any help explaining why this doesn't behave as I expect would be wonderful.

Tested in the Visual Studio Online Compiler, and Clang.

Comment: I'm also very unsure about how best to word the question, if anyone feels they have a more technical way to phrase it please change it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::array` is an [aggregate type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), it does not have a constructor that takes an `initializer-list`, so you need two brackets for each `std::array`:

```
std::vector<std::array<std::array<double, 3>, 2>> arr =
{
  {{
    {{2, 1, 0}},
    {{1, 1, 0}}
  }}
};
```

You may enable such warning with `-Wmissing-braces` in g++ (clang enables this warning by default with `-Wall`).

Comment: Could you elaborate. This kindof makes sense but I am now having trouble understanding exactly what has happened to produce the result I get. Seems like my original code should fail to compile to me now!

Comment: @sji I will update my answer with detailed information as soon as I can but the idea is that missing fields in an aggregate initialization is filled with 0.

Comment: Having spent a bit longer reading the linked page I now understand. Thanks

Comment: @sji You can enable warning for this kind of thing with `-Wmissing-braces` in g++ (clang has these by default with `-Wall`).

Comment: @Holt, sji, could you please explain how this works? Reading the page on aggregate initialization didn't help much, and I can't see how double curly braces fit the syntax at all.

Comment: @Semisonic It's actually related to `std::array`. `std::array` is an aggregate which behaves as-if it contains a member `data` that is a `T[N]`. To initialize a `int[3]`, you would do `{ 1, 2, 3 }`. To initialize a struct `A` with a single member of type `int` you would do `A a{ 1 }`. Now, the member is not `int` but `int[3]`, so simply replace the `1` with `{ 1, 2, 3, }` and you'll get the double brackets `{{ 1, 2, 3 }}`. There is an example at the end of the link page, but note that some rules have changed since C++11. In particular, you are now allowed to omit those extract brackets.